# Button as a variable

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am trying to have a variable set to a buttons label.
I have something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

var myVariable = String()

@IBAction func ButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    myVariable = myButton.titleLabel
}
```

Can anyone tell my how I can make this work?

Comment: Tip for your code improvement : Function name start's with small latter.

Comment: @Rolexboy8008 Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: When posting a question, be sure to include relevant error messages and point out the line causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, you're just missing the `text` property. Also you might want to set your variable as an optional.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

var myVariable: String?

@IBAction func ButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    myVariable = myButton.titleLabel?.text
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, It gave me a few errors at first but I changed it to "myButton.titleLabel!.tekst!" and now it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Be carefully with force unwrapping of titleLable and text. Add this line at first: `guard let text = myButton.titleLabel?.text else { return }`. Than write `myVariable = text`

Comment: This answer won't compile. Please fix. You can't assign a `String?` to a variable of type `String`.

Answer (score 2):

`titleLabel` is an instance of `UILabel`. Your `myVariable` is a String property. That does not match typewise. You can access `titleLabel` directly, as in:

```
myVariable = myButton.titleLabel?.text ?? ""
```

But `UIButton` class defines a [`title(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624022-title) method to access title of the button for various states.

Thus, in your case I would recommend using following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

var myVariable = String()

@IBAction func ButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    myVariable = myButton.title(for: .normal) ?? ""
}
```